# small problem with optional section in NSIS with HM NSIS editor

Tags: installation, nsis

I have simple little problem:

According to the [docs here](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.6) I should have a **optional** section which should allow the user to check it off right?

I have a section like this:

```
Section "SayHello"
 DetailPrint "blah blah"
 MessageBox MB_OK "hello"
SectionEnd
```

I've tried all sorts of combinations and tweaks but it never shows up an as optional check, the message box just executes every time no matter what. Except of course if I add an `/o` it just does throw the message box at all, but no option to check it on/off.

Its just eating me a little and I cannot seem to figure what is wrong?

Also, are sections **executed in the order they are defined?**

Note: My whole code, is generated by [HM NIS editor](http://hmne.sourceforge.net/) I just ran the wizard for a basic installer and saved the script, then, I added this section. It also used **Modern UI**.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the ability to toggle sections, you need to insert a components page before the instfiles page.

Yes, sections execute in the order they are defined in the script.

Comment: +1 thanks! How do I do that with the Modern UI scripts, the don't seem to have any page defined!

Comment: @giddy: !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS See http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Modern%20UI/Readme.html for more info